# Is there simple example or demo to show how to play with this community?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I read questions at this community for while and feel they are funny:)

But I really don't know what the questions are playing with, especially the meaning behind the title:(

I have no idea what they are talking about, is there any beginner instruction to join this community?

Comment: I know how you feel. I'm still basically new here. To start, you should go in depth into your favorite languages. Learn all the hidden features. Use the `Tips for golfing in xyz` topics for help. Then, start posting answers! It doesn't matter if your answer isn't the best as long as you explain how it works. If you have a great idea for a question, make sure it's not a duplicate and follows all the rules, then post it in the sandbox to get feedback.

Comment: In addition to Alex's great answer, [feel free to join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) - people in there are usually glad to help newcomers learn the ropes. :)

Comment: @MartinBüttner [Chat privilege](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) is granted at 20 reputation. OP currently has 1.

Comment: @Rainbolt I believe you only need the rep on any one site (other than SO or Meta, which have their own chat instances), and the OP does have more than 20 rep on other sites. (Might even be network rep that unlocks the privilege, I'm not sure about that.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Perhaps, but I can't test it because I automatically get 101 rep on every site I join. The page I linked to leads me to believe otherwise. "Your reputation on chat is the same as your reputation **on the parent site**."

Comment: @Rainbolt I *think* that refers to the site of the chat user's parent account, not of the site the chatroom belongs to, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Rainbolt [This would back it up.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257821/201409) It's not written by an employee though. You know who could test it? The OP. ;) (*hint*...)

Answer (score 17):

Hello and Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! I'm delighted that you'd like you join our community. We're glad to have you.

To get a feel for the community and how to contribute:

- You can start with the [Tour](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/tour), which to be honest isn't terribly informative, but it's a start.
- Check out the [Help Center](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/help) for more details on what kind of challenges and submissions are acceptable.
- Take a look around the site and see how people do things. That, in my opinion, is the easiest way to get a feel for the community. It sounds like you've already been doing that, which is great!
- I recommend trying your hand at answering a couple challenges and if you feel like writing your own, you can post it to the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where you can get feedback on it before it goes to the main site.

If you come across challenges that you don't understand immediately, don't fret! Often others will have the same questions. In that case you can leave a comment on the post asking for clarification. Challenges should contain sufficient detail so that a broad range of people can participate. Sometimes the subject matter is highly specialized, often pertaining to advanced mathematics, but if that's not your forte then we have plenty of other challenges to choose from.

If you have any further questions along the way, you've already found the perfect place to ask them: Meta!